# Converting Python AST/code into a CFG in Python

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, pypy, cpython, control-flow

From my research it seems the main CFG generator for Python code in Python is the PyPy Flow Model (http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/objspace.html#the-flow-model) but it seems to have the limitations which come from using RPython. Most of the limitations do not hinder CFG generation but there are a few which do, such as restricting for loops to built-in types and the generator limitations.

CPython appears to generate a 'complete' CFG in compile.c which it then emits its bytecode from. However this is all done in C, while my work so far is all done in Python. There also seems to be a bit of hacking required to extract the CFG from CPython.

Is there no 'complete' CFG generator for Python code implemented in Python?

I am not completely against the idea of building one myself which ties in with the ast module, but I would like to make sure I know all of my options before I dive into that.

Comment: PyPy itself works like CPython but is written in Python, so you could take the parts of ``pypy/interpreter/{pyparser,astcompiler}`` that interest you.